# Document versus Dynamic Document Property

Tags: boomi

What is the key difference between Document and Dynamic Document Property?

We were trying to use these properties in Boomi atomsphere process development but not able to decide which is the best to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Document Properties:** Document properties are additional information or "metadata" about an individual document as it executes through a process.

**Usage:** I have used document properties of Disk, FTP, SFTP for creating file names. Also document properties of Mail can be used to create Body, filename, subject, from Address and To Address.

**Dynamic Document Properties:** Dynamic document properties are properties that the process developer can define and use to temporarily store additional pieces of information about a given document.

**Usage:** I have used this to create an ALL_INDEX to get all the data from data cache

Answer (score 2):

**Document properties:** -  are additional information or "metadata" about an individual document as it executes through a process. The values contained in properties are separate from the document's actual data contents. These properties remain with a given document as it progresses through the various process steps, even as the document data itself is manipulated through Map steps or outbound connector calls.

There are two types of document properties:

**standard document properties** :contain run-time specific information such as connector or trading partner details.

**Dynamic document properties** : are arbitrary values that you can use to temporarily store related values.